# PyTorch pack_padded_sequence Runtime Error

Tags: pytorch, nlp

Error

```
in pack_padded_sequence
    _VF._pack_padded_sequence(input, lengths, batch_first)
RuntimeError: Length of all samples has to be greater than 0, but found an element in 'lengths' that is <= 0
```

Im having trouble while to pack padded sequence. I do not run into this problem while I'm training my model with dataset. So I don't think its my dataset or model problem. (If so, please tell me how do I check)

My Config

```
batch_size = 128
embedding_dim = 256
num_layers = 1
hidden_size = 64
```

My Encoder Class.

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=len(config.chatbot_ws_input),
                                      embedding_dim=config.chatbot_embedding_dim,
                                      padding_idx=config.chatbot_ws_input.PAD
                                      )
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size=config.chatbot_embedding_dim,
                          num_layers=config.chatbot_encoder_num_layers,
                          hidden_size=config.chatbot_encoder_hidden_size,
                          batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, input, input_len):
        """
        :param input_len: 
        :param input: [batch_size, max_len]
        :return:
        """
        embedded = self.embedding(input)  # embedded --> [batch_size, max_len, embedding_dim]
        embedded = pack_padded_sequence(embedded, input_len, batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)  

        out, hidden = self.gru(embedded)
     
        out, out_length = pad_packed_sequence(out, batch_first=True, padding_value=config.chatbot_ws_input.PAD)
        return out, hidden
```

Eval()

```
def eval(by_word=True):
    seq2seq = Seq2Seq().to(config.device)
    seq2seq.load_state_dict(torch.load(config.chatbot_model_save_path))

    while True:
        _input = input("Please Enter: ")
        _input = cut(_input, by_word=by_word)
        input_length = torch.LongTensor(len(_input) if len(_input) > config.chatbot_input_max_len else config.chatbot_input_max_len)
        _input = torch.LongTensor(config.chatbot_ws_input.transform(_input, max_len=config.chatbot_input_max_len))

        print(len(_input))
        print(len(input_length))

        indices = np.array(seq2seq.evaluate(_input, input_length)).flatten()  
        output = config.chatbot_ws_target.inverse_transform(indices)
        print("answer: ", output)
```

## What I'm expecting is:

1. I'll give an input, for example "你好吗" to a cut() function
2. It will returns ['你','好','吗'], and then being passed to my encoder for pack_padded_sequence.
3. But the error pops up.

In my previous experience, this error means that my dataset contain contents that is len() = 0, but I have filter them out in my cut() function, so there is currently no empty space in my processed dataset. Below is my sample input dataset.

input.txt

```
高 富 帅
你
呵 呵
今 天 是 谁 的 生 日
你 敢 不 敢
我 想 要 女 朋 友
无 聊
```

## What I have tried:

- I have tried both re-process my dataset, and re-train my model. They both works fine.
- I have also checked all the size() of my parameters, all were in expected size.
- But Error came back when I tries to eval the model.

## Biggest Doubt

The biggest doubt is that I didn't have this error when I was training samples (I had it before, but I added null value filtering). But when I want to evaluate the model, the error comes again.

Wondering if anyone has a similar problem? Am I missing something that hasn't been investigated?